# Align button at the bottom in Advanced Post widget

Tags: css, wordpress, flexbox, wordpress-theming, elementor

I am creating a page with the Advanced Post widget but am unable to align the Read More button at the bottom of the column. I am trying the below code but it's not working

```
.pp-post-excerpt {
    margin-bottom: 55px;
}
.pp-posts-button {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure what you want but you can use flex box for move button to bottom of card
If you need more say

Answer (score 0):

The following css will cause the Read More to stick to the bottom of the column. I tested it using the browsers dev-tools on your site so it should work.

```css
.pp-post-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: start;
  height: 100%;
}
.pp-posts-button {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

Comment: I just tried it's not working.

Comment: @SamRicc did you make sure you have to the proper selectors? I used these to identify the elements within the column, but you might need to use more specific ones in order to overwrite existing styles.